# Strategy for proper version control of "auto-filled" text files

Tags: org-mode, version-control, auto-fill-mode

I like `auto-fill-mode` a lot because it makes text fit into my screen even when I have two buffers side-by-side.
My problem is that a **small wording change may trigger auto-fill to reformat a whole paragraph**, and that doesn't play well with version controlling, i.e., git.

I can't track my small changes anymore, because the whole paragraph is changed.

I was wondering if anyone has a suggestion on how to deal with this problem.
Is there a "visual-auto-fill", which doesn't take care of newlines but just visually displays text in a proper manner?

Since I plan to export files to LaTeX and HTML, I don't care if there are no newlines at all in the saved document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you want `visual-line-mode`. See the Emacs manual section 14.22 (run `M-: (info "(emacs)Visual Line Mode")` to jump right to it inside Emacs).

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for the quick answer

Answer (score 0):

Late to this but perhaps an alternative take on this might help.

### Premise

It's useful to wrap lines at a defined length...

1. It fits into most buffers for users screen resolution/settings.
2. It makes it easier to find errors in what would otherwise be long lines. **This is my main preference for having lines hard-wrapped**.

### Problem

> My problem is that **a small wording change may trigger auto-fill to reformat a whole paragraph**, and that doesn't play well with version controlling, i.e., git.
>
> I can't track my small changes anymore, because the whole paragraph is changed.

For Git at least there is something that can help although it requires discipline and may not be perfect.

Git allows you to ignore particular revisions when viewing `git blame` by adding commit hashes to a specific (configurable) file the default is `.git-blame-ignore-revs`. I won't reproduce what I've written elsewhere and instead point to an article I wrote on how to do this...[Who's to blame](https://ns-rse.github.io/posts/whos_to_blame/).

This is /really/ useful when dealing with legacy code.

### Great for linting legacy code, but how to ignore small changes?

Its not that useful though for the situation described as typically it is /changes/ that alter code/text and we you /want/ to incorporate the changes but ignore the code breaks when making meaningful changes rather than just linting existing code as described above.

I don't know of a way around this in the Git version control itself, after all, adjusting carriage returns in a set of contiguous rows *is* the same in terms of version control as adding text to a line, both are changes.

Gut there is a way of handling this visually when viewing the differences via the say `git diff` which is to leverage the parameter/settings for [`color-moved-ws`](https://git-scm.com/docs/diff-options/2.19.0#Documentation/diff-options.txt---color-moved-wsltmodesgt).

There are a few options available, probably `ignore-space-space` would be most appropriate here, it ignores changes in whitespace at end of lines, but considers all other white space to be equivalent. The caveat is that you then have to make sure you don't put any double-spaces in anywhere. ;-)

But as a consequence you get slightly different colours when doing `git diff` locally and perhaps on your choice of Forge too (I think Git{Hub,Lab} both do this not sure about Codeberg/SourceHut).